Snowflake Ingesting Data from Rest API
I'm currently working on a project where I need to ingest data from Oracle HCM into Snowflake using REST API with username and password credentials. I've already explored the endpoints and URLs using Postman and successfully retrieved JSON formatted data.
However, I'm unsure about how to efficiently ingest this data into Snowflake. Could anyone who has experience with similar integrations offer some guidance or best practices? Any insights or pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
I'm unsure about how to efficiently ingest this data into Snowflake.

This is a good place for you to start  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/index

You can use External Access Integration for connectivity Of Snowflake to external API
Try this
[https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/external-network-access/creating-using-external-network-access][1]
